# Type error: Argument 1 passed to BelongsToMany::formatSyncList() must be of the type array, null given, called in

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have upload form which user can add posts with tags. When I enter tag in the input field I've got this error

> FatalThrowableError in BelongsToMany.php line 866:
>
> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::formatSyncList() must be of the type array, null given, called in

This is what I have in `Tag` model

```
public function itemTags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'item_tag');
}
```

In my `Item` model

```
public function taggs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'item_tag');
}
```

The field in my view

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('inputTags', 'Tags', array('class'=> 'col-sm-2 control-label')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('tags', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'inputTags']) !!}         
</div>
```

And the controller

```
public function store( ItemRequest $request )
{

    $image = $request->file('image');
    $filename=null;

    if( $image && $image->isValid()){
        $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $uploadPath = public_path(). '/uploads';
        $filename = rand(111,999). '.'. $extension;
        $image->move($uploadPath, $filename);
    }

    $item = new Item;
    $item->title = $request['title'];
    $item->category_id = $request['category_id'];
    $item->description = $request['description'];
    $item->user_id = Auth::user()->id;        
    $item->url = $request['url'];
    $item->image = $filename;

    if($item->save()){
        if(!is_null($filename)) {
            $item_image = new Item_Images;
            $item_image->image = $filename;
            $item_image->item_id = $item->id;
            $item_image->published = 1;
            $item_image->save();
        }

        $request->session()->flash('alert-success','Item added successfully.');
    }else
        $request->session()->flash('alert-error','Can not add item now. Plese tyr again!!.');

    $item->taggs()->sync($request->tags);
    return redirect()->route('frontend.user.myitems');
}
```

The error is on this line

```
    $item->taggs()->sync($request->tags);
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Try adding a `dd($request->all())` at the top of your controller method to check if the `$request` variable contains tags

Comment: Yes, I see it the array: `"tags" => "Tag"`

Comment: There you go, `"Tag"`is a string, not an array, that's the reason of the error

Comment: So the input you would have is like Tag1, Tag2, Tag3 inside the text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your request of tag value `$request->tags` get empty, Try to call sync like:

```
$syncTagData = array();
//Passing empty array if tag request is empty...
if(!empty($request->tags)){
    $syncTagData= $request->tags;
}

$item->taggs()->sync($syncTagData);
```

### Update

If your request `$request->tags` not the type array, try below code:

```
$syncTagData = array();
//Passing empty array if tag request is empty...
if(!empty($request->tags)){
  array_push($syncTagData, $request->tags);
}
```

Comment: Ok, check my *UPDATE* answer

Comment: Hm, now is working without the error. So the second example is if there is no array, the array_push will create one, right?

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to help, Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Today I got same error in many to many relationship between a plot and features. 
Reason behind this was user wasn't selecting the features and null was passing to **sync()**

`$plot->featureset()->sync($request->features)`;

Solution:

`$feature_set = ($request->features) != null)  ? $request->features : [];`

`$plot->featureset()->sync($feature_set);`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for my project.

```
    if (isset($request->tags)) {

        $intern->tags()->sync($request->input('tags'), false);

    } else {

        $intern->tags()->sync(array());

    }
```